# Java - Getting same day of week for next year

Tags: java

I was looking for a way to make optimum of Java 8's LocalDate to find next year's date which falls on same day of week.

For example today is 1rd March 2022 - Tuesday. Assume this is the input date, the the output date that I expect to get is 28th Feb 2023, because its the same day (Tuesday) for next year

One option that I tried was adding 364 days as shown in the example

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    LocalDate currentDate= LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println("Current Date: " + currentDate + " Day" currentDate.getDayOfWeek().name());
    System.out.println("Next Year's date: " + currentDate.plusDays(364) + " Next year day: " +currentDate.plusDays(364).getDayOfWeek().name());
  }
```

This works but may have drawback with leap years.

Other option is to add 1 year to current date and do a while loop check for dayOfWeek for each day - 1

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'd go for the "add 1 year and subtract" option. You don't necessary need a loop; you can use the value of both `DayOfWeek` instances to immediately calculate how many days to subtract. It's basically `(d1.getValue() - d2.getValue() + 7) % 7`.

Comment: "but may have drawback with leap years." What drawbacks? That seems like exactly what you want. (Unless I have misunderstood what you mean, in which case you should describe exactly the result you want)

Comment: You don't need to add 364 days (52 weeks * 7 days) manually, you can use [`plusWeeks()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusWeeks-long-) to achieve the same effect

The problem with this approach is that yes, over time adding 364 by 364 days is going to be 1 or 2 days off each year. Instead, find which week your date is in. March 1st is in the 9th week of the year. Then, at your desired year, find the 9th week and find Tuesday in it.

You are going to face hurdles with 53-week years, I suggest looking at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: @Sweeper With 364 day for leap years will it not be 1 or 2 days off eventually

Comment: What do you mean by "eventually"? Are you going to be doing this repeatedly? Are you trying to get a similar date with the same day of week after N years? In that case it is going to be off by a maximum of 3 or 4 days.

Comment: Not n year, just one year(from any date specified as input)

Comment: @Sweeper Can you please mention the same in answer and I will mark it as answer as I made 1000 odd test cases to check if for any date adding 364 days does not give same day of week

Comment: @SandeepNair Huh? Did I (accidentally) answer your question? Did you think that adding 364 days was not always going to work?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, for some reason I though with leap year when you add 364 days you would be 1 day short to be exact same day of week. Because I initially tried plusYears(1).minusDays(1) and for leap year had to do minusdays(2) and thought would be the same with adding 364 days but I was wrong